# Do you need to grease wheel hubs

Tags: wheels, grease, hub

I just replaced the wheel hubs on my car and I was wondering if you need to pack the whole spindle with grease like you do on the older style of wheel bearings?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the bearings, if they have rubber seals on each side (ie sealed for life...) then no, but if they are "open" then you need to have grease there.